# Что нужно сделать, чтобы информация в input, при обновлении страницы, не пропадала?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на сайте не пропадала информация введенная в форму с input, но не знаю как это сделать. Может есть какой-нибудь скрипт? А если и нет, то как его написать?

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
     <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="поиск" aria-label="Search">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Если, что, то можно по-проще? Я не очень хорош в терминологии

Comment: Сохраняйте данные в Local Storage или Cookies, а после перезагрузки восстанавливайте.

Comment: А как сохранять введенные данные  в cookies, при перезагрузке?

Comment: Надо повесить на <input> событие какое-нибудь типа onkeyup и каждый раз сохранять новое значение в хранилище

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("txt_1").value = getSavedValue("txt_1");
document.getElementById("txt_2").value = getSavedValue("txt_2");

function saveValue(e) {
  var id = e.id;
  var val = e.value;
  localStorage.setItem(id, val);
}

function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(v) === null) {
    return "";
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt_1" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' />
<input type="text" id="txt_2" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' />
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930144/keep-input-value-after-refresh-page)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ удовлетворяет вашим условиям, вы можете принять его.

Comment: Сделал бы, правда я на форуме недавно, не знаю как это сделать..

Comment: Галочка слева от ответа.